# Stretch images contained in 1 div across screen

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, stretch

Probably a simple fix here, but I have 3x images in line I want to stretch across the browser window, no matter what resolution.

I've messed around with percentages in CSS but I can only seem to control one object.

My guess is to possibly create an individual div for each image, then assign each div a percentage of the screen, so 1/3 of the screen's width is reserved for each image - this will then stretch / re-size depending on resolution.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction? Not sure if I'm thinking too much into this.

Cheers!

Comment: Please add your HTML or create a fiddle

Comment: Without any code it is impossible to answer your question. Can you create a fiddle for it.

Comment: Right. We could say `width:33.3%`, but as you've already "messed around with percentages", you've already tried that. So what goes wrong? We can't see what goes wrong!

Comment: Sorry guys, was trying to do this at work and didn't have enough time to post the code:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/upr0h897/2/ - I basically want the 3x images to stretch evenly across the browser window, depending on the resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add:

```
width: 33.3%;
```

To your:

```
img.selector1 {}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, I guess I just put the 33.3% in the wrong bit, always sticking things in the wrong hole.

Comment: Haha! No worries mate.